# Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries NuGet Package on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, dotnet-httpclient, base-class-library

As of this writing, The Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries NuGet package (Microsoft.Net.Http) is at version `2.2.13`.  However, this version comes with a disclaimer that it is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, despite being required by System.Web.Http.SelfHost. (And indeed, it does cause issues with Visual Studio 2010, as does the dependent library `Microsoft.Bcl.Build`.)

My question is, which version should I be using?  Available previous versions are `2.1.10`, `2.0.20710.0`, and `2.0.20505.0`.

I'll give `2.1.10` a try and report back, but if anyone already has the answer, please let me know.

Comment: Within 30 seconds of writing this question, version `2.2.15` appeared on NuGet.  Still no VS 2010 support, but I was amused.

Comment: The latest package should work when targeting .Net 4 with VS2010.  The unsupported wording has to do with other frameworks that aren't supported by VS 2010.  Can you let me know what issues you are seeing?

Comment: @TheESJ If I start a new project with an ASP.NET MVC 4 template and update all the NuGet packages except the Microsoft.Net.Http, everything works fine, but once I upgrade Microsoft.Net.Http it breaks the build with assembly reference errors.  The added dependency with Microsoft.Bcl.Build also introduces [other problems](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793340/microsoft-bcl-build-1-0-7-cannot-load-packages-config-when-building-within-visual-studio-2010), but the HTTP Client Libraries don't have the dependency on Microsoft.Bcl.Build in version 2.0.20710.0.

Answer (score 2):

The highest version of `Microsoft.Net.Http` for .NET 4.0 supported in Visual Studio 2010 appears to be `2.0.20710.0`.  Fortunately, the Web API and self-hosting libraries I'm using don't depend on anything higher than that, so I should be good.